# Issue in getting json key value from the JSON String in Flutter

Tags: json, string, flutter

I am getting below json from the api response:

> "metadata": "{"title":"Payables - Due in Last 30
> Days","marketModel":1,"marketDropdownId":"payables_last_30_days","marketOptions":[{"id":1,"name":"Wholesale","icon":"fas
> fa-dolly-flatbed-alt"},{"id":2,"name":"Retail","icon":"fas
> fa-store-alt","suboptions":[{"id":3,"name":"California","key":"CA"},{"id":4,"name":"Florida","key":"FL"},{"id":5,"name":"New
> Jersey","key":"NJ"},{"id":6,"name":"New
> York","key":"NY"}]}],"tableColumns":[{"label":"Posted","key":"posted","headerClass":"u-pg-w-pr-14"},{"label":"Vendor","key":"vendor","headerClass":"u-pg-w-pr-51"},{"label":"Due
> Date","key":"date","headerClass":"u-pg-w-pr-14"},{"label":"Amount","key":"amount","type":"currency","headerClass":"u-pg-w-pr-21
> text-right"}]}"

I need to get the value of **'title'** key, So I have tried as below:

```
Text(jsonDecode(metadata)['title']
```

where metadata the json string as above:

```
   dynamic metadata;
```

But I could not get it and getting error regarding it. What might be the issue?

Comment: Based on your data, you are getting string as value instead of Map.

Comment: Yes I want title key value from this String

Comment: You response needed to be `"metadata": {"title":"Payables -` instead of `"metadata": "{"title":"Payables -`

Comment: But I can get it this way : jsonDecode(managedData.metaData[i])['label'] ?? "" for this response: "metadata": "{\"label\":\"Pending COLAs\\\/Formulas\",\"valueOneSource\":\"colas\",\"valueOneType\":\"integer\",\"valueTwoSource\":\"formulas\",\"valueTwoType\":\"integer\"}",  .... to get label value.. then Why I am not able to do the same for 'title'  ? confused here..

Comment: "and getting error" what error?

Comment: @pskink I could not get exact error.. since its throwing Observer related error.